# Is it possible to use Soundex (or other SQL functions) in LinqToSql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, soundex

I'm refactoring some code currently implemented in stored procedures to use LinqToSql (for use in training). Is it possible to use SQL functions in a linqToSql Query?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some helpful information from a MSDN Forum Post.  [Soundex and LINQ](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2940301&SiteID=1).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself yet but the below method [originally posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993087/linq-to-sql-soundex-possible) seems to be the best possible solution.

```
    [Function(Name="SoundEx", IsComposable = true)]
    public string SoundsLike(string input)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```